# Как вывести данные из базы данных SQLite в ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Добавил заранее созданную базу данных SQLite в свой проект AndroidStudio. Сам проект представляет собой справочник на основе Navigations Drawer Views Activity. У каждого пункта меню есть свой id. Так вот, я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на пункт меню ListView заполнялся определенными данными из таблицы моей базы данных.

Код класса DataBaseHelper, где осуществляется подключение базы данных:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private static String DB_NAME = "diplom.db";
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1;
    public static final String TABLE = "dishes"; // название таблицы в бд
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID_CATEGORY = "id_category";
    private Context myContext;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + DB_NAME;
    }

    public void create_db() {
        File file = new File(DB_PATH);
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            try(InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int lenght;
                while ((lenght = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, lenght);
                }
                myOutput.flush();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.d("DataBaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase open()throws SQLException {

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Код класса MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private SharedPreferences def_pref;
private ListView list;
DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor userCursor;
SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        list = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        );
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        dataBaseHelper.create_db();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        db = dataBaseHelper.open();
        userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DataBaseHelper.TABLE,null);
        String[] headers = new String[]{DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_ID_CATEGORY};
        userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.content_main, userCursor, headers,
                new int[]{R.id.id_soup},0);
        list.setAdapter(userAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        if (id == R.id.id_settings)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.id_soup)
        {
            userCursor = db.rawQuery("select " + DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " from " + DataBaseHelper.TABLE
            + " where " + DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_ID_CATEGORY + " =1", null);
            userCursor.moveToFirst();

            userCursor.close();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Происходить это по задумке должно в методе onNavigationItemSelected. При выполнении существующего кода ничего не происходит. Не могу додуматься, как это сделать :c

Comment: `userAdapter.changeCursor(userCursor);` Манипуляции с курсором, кроме получения из базы - убрать.

Comment: Извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос, но какие именно манипуляции с курсором мне следует удалить?

Comment: Вы получили курсор из базы, отдали его адаптеру - больше ничего с ним делать не нужно, а тем более закрывать. А у вас адаптер вообще отображает данные? Мне помнится он вроде требовал, чтобы в курсоре была колонка `_id`

Comment: Не поздновато для диплома то?) Посмотрите более свежие примеры использования `SQLite`. Ваш текущий код будет работать только с костылями(вижу уже кучу проблем в `onResume`). Плюс вообще не понятно, зачем вы получаете курсор и закрываете его, так никуда и не передав...